# Как создать приложение для Windows7 для отправки текстового сообщения с картинкой в viber?

Tags: c#, api, rest, viber

На пример мне нужно приложение WinForm для того, чтобы отправить сообщение в viber.
Я получаю "TOKEN".
Я не понимаю что делать дальше.

Я изучил

- Viber REST API  - [ссылка](https://developers.viber.com/docs/api/rest-bot-api/#viber-rest-api)
- Пример бота C # - [ссылка](https://gist.github.com/eranziman/dc27385f6674c3d0bc4a3bcf784344d6)
- github.com. Поиск - "viber bot" - [ссылка](https://github.com/search?l=C%23&q=viber%20bot&type=Repositories)

Но я не понимаю, как это собрать в одну систему и выполнить приложение.

Вопросы:
 - Как создать приложение для Windows7 для отправки текстового сообщения с картинкой в viber?
 - Меня интересует краткая инструкция. Если не сложно, то с примерами кода и (или) ссылки.

**Обновление_1.**
Пробую  использовать Пример бота C# - [ссылка](https://gist.github.com/eranziman/dc27385f6674c3d0bc4a3bcf784344d6)

**Изменения.**
Было  `public partial class ViberDummyBot : System.Web.UI.Page`
Стало  `public partial class ViberDummyBot`

Получаю ошибки:

- Имя "Response" не существует в текущем контексте.
- Имя "Request" не существует в текущем контексте. Тип или имя    пространства имен
- "Script" не существует в пространстве имен "System.Web"

**Вопрос:** как использовать этот класс для решения задачи поставленной в вопросе?

**Обновление_2.**
Изменён метод. `replyEmptyResponse()`
Было:

```
private void replyEmptyResponse()
{
  Response.Write("{}");
}
```

Стало:

```
    private async void replyEmptyResponse()
            {
                // Create a New HttpClient object and dispose it when done, so the app doesn't leak resources
                using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    // Call asynchronous network methods in a try/catch block to handle exceptions
                    try
                    {                        
                        // HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(); // test
// или
                        // HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("{}", ); // test


                        //  response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                        // string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        // Above three lines can be replaced with new helper method below
                        // string responseBody = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);

                        // Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
                    }
                    catch (HttpRequestException e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\nException Caught!");
                        Console.WriteLine("Message :{0} ", e.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: А в чем конкретно проблема? Ссылка на пример бота на C# отлично подходит. Проблема переписать это на WinForm? Или что? Такое ощущение, что вы просите пример готовой программы.

Comment: @Valery Losev Да просто уже начитался... голова кругом... Ни как в систему не могу выстроить... Пример не обязательно... Я не могу понять: **1.** п.4 инструкции `Вызовите веб-ловушку (https://chatapi.viber.com/pa/set_webhook) с токеном вашей учетной записи и вашим URL-адресом ViberDummyBot.aspx (должен иметь доверенный сертификат ssl)` **2.**  Я не могу понять логику приложения. Как оно должно работать? Может не сложно привести пример логику с фрагментами кода, по принципу: 1. Подключение (фрагмент кода). 2. Отправить сообщение (фрагмент кода).

Comment: @ValeryLosev **1.** Обновил вопрос.  См. `Обновление_1.` **2.** См. предыдущее сообщение

Comment: Response и Request необходимы для отправки запросов. В WinForm таких свойств нет. Для отправки запросов с WinForm используй HttpClient https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @ValeryLosev **1.** `Response`. Метод `replyEmptyResponse()` наверное будет выглядеть как-то так (см. `Обновление_2`). Как правильно сделать не понимаю. **2.** Что делать с `Request` и `Script`. Они я так понимаю, обрабатывают страницу `web form`. Что предполагал автор, чтобы было на странице? Хотя наверное чат... А что делать если у меня нет страницы? **3.** Может проще использовать github.com/edanila/viber.bot [ссылка](https://github.com/edanila/viber.bot) ? Хотя и тут вопрос: С чего начать?. Я понимаю, что подключить как библиотеку, а как подключиться к viber, как отправить сообщение?